# Writing unit test for Salesforce custom controller using AggregateResults function

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, aggregate-functions, apex

Long time SFDC admin, diving into APEX for the first time.

I built a custom controller for a Dashboard component (visualforce page).  Controller works, but need unit tests to push to production (dont ask - org suffers from low coverage).

Here is the controller:

```
public with sharing class retrieveMRR {

public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }

public retrieveMRR() {
    AggregateResult[] results =
        [SELECT SUM(Opportunity.MRR_Projected_EOM__c) MRRtm, 
SUM(Opportunity.Billing_MRR_Last_Month__c) MRRlm, 
SUM(Opportunity.Billing_MRR_M_minus2__c) MRRlm2,
SUM(Opportunity.Billing_MRR_Last_Month_Pilot_Change__c) chgPlusPilotlm ,
SUM(Opportunity.Billing_MRR_Last_Month_Pilot_Change2__c) chgMinusPilotlm ,
SUM(Opportunity.Billing_MRR_Last_Month_NPilot_Change__c) chgPlusNPilotlm , 
SUM(Opportunity.Billing_MRR_Last_Month_NPilot_Change2__c) chgMinusNPilotlm FROM Opportunity ];
    Summaries = new List<Summary>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
    Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));


 }

}
public class Summary {
    public Decimal MRRtm { get; private set; }
    public Decimal MRRlm { get; private set; }
    public Decimal MRRlm2 { get; private set; }
    public Decimal chgPlusPilotlm { get; private set; }
    public Decimal chgMinusPilotlm { get; private set; }
    public Decimal chgPlusNPilotlm { get; private set; }
    public Decimal chgMinusNPilotlm { get; private set; }

    public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
    MRRtm = (Decimal) ar.get('MRRtm');
    MRRlm = (Decimal) ar.get('MRRlm');
    MRRlm2 = (Decimal) ar.get('MRRlm2');
    chgPlusPilotlm = (Decimal) ar.get('chgPlusPilotlm');
    chgMinusPilotlm = (Decimal) ar.get('chgMinusPilotlm');
    chgPlusNPilotlm = (Decimal) ar.get('chgPlusNPilotlm');
    chgMinusNPilotlm = (Decimal) ar.get('chgMinusNPilotlm');

    }
  } 
 }
```

Here is the Visualforce page if necessary

```
<apex:page controller="retrieveMRR">
<apex:pageBlock title="MRR"> 
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!Summaries}" var="summary">

     <apex:outputText style="font-weight:800; font-size:16px" value="Month"></apex:outputText>
     <apex:outputText style="font-weight:800; font-size:16px" value="Value"></apex:outputText>
     <apex:outputText style="font-weight:800; font-size:16px" value="+ New / - Lost"></apex:outputText> 


     <apex:outputText style="font-weight:800" value="{0,date,MMMM YYYY} (actual)"><apex:param value="{!TODAY()-60}" />  </apex:outputText>  
     <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value=""><apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!summary.MRRlm2}" /></apex:outputText> </apex:outputLink>
     <apex:outputText value=""></apex:outputText> 

    <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="   change"><apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" /> </apex:outputText>  
    <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value=""><apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!summary.MRRlm-summary.MRRlm2}" /></apex:outputText> </apex:outputLink>
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!null}" /></apex:outputText>

    <apex:outputText style="font-weight:400 ; align: center" value="Pilot"> </apex:outputText>  
    <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value=""><apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!summary.chgPlusPilotlm+summary.chgMinusPilotlm}" /></apex:outputText></apex:outputLink>
    <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value=""><apex:outputText value="+{0, number, $###,###,##0}/{1, number, $###,###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!summary.chgPlusPilotlm}" />
    <apex:param value="{!summary.chgMinusPilotlm}" /> </apex:outputText></apex:outputLink>

    <apex:outputText style="font-weight:400 ; align: center" value="Non-Pilot"> </apex:outputText>  
    <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value=""><apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!summary.chgPlusNPilotlm+summary.chgMinusNPilotlm}" /></apex:outputText></apex:outputLink>
    <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value=""><apex:outputText value="+{0, number, $###,###,##0}/{1, number, $###,###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!summary.chgPlusNPilotlm}" />
    <apex:param value="{!summary.chgMinusNPilotlm}" /> </apex:outputText></apex:outputLink>


   <apex:outputText style="font-weight:800" value="{0,date,MMMM YYYY} (actual)"><apex:param value="{!TODAY()-31}" /> </apex:outputText>  
   <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value=""><apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!summary.MRRlm}" /></apex:outputText> </apex:outputLink>
   <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!null}" /></apex:outputText>

    <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="change"></apex:outputText>  
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!summary.MRRtm-summary.MRRlm}" /></apex:outputText> 
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!null}" /></apex:outputText>

    <apex:outputText style="font-weight:800" value="{0,date,MMMM YYYY} (projected)"><apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" /> </apex:outputText>  
    <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value=""><apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!summary.MRRtm}" /></apex:outputText> </apex:outputLink>
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}"><apex:param value="{!null}" /></apex:outputText>



    </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I've done unit tests for other APEX controllers, but I don't know how to test a controller that is just a Aggregate Function.  Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of googling and soul searching to figure this out.

The solution I was looking for was expedient: I'm not writing data in this class.  I don't need a data factory and crazy apparatus to test this.   It was really hard to take the examples out there and apply them to a simple class that just queries the database and then prints values.

As such, the test I wrote was simple and works for my purposes (to meet code coverage limits):

```html
@isTest
public class badtest {
    static testMethod void runTest() {
         retrieveMRR a = new retrieveMRR();
            
  } 
  }
```

I simply created a class and then instantiated the class I was trying to test.  BAM 100% code coverage.

Hope this helps those learning APEX in order to build Visualforce pages for dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a test class as a data factory (see trailhead [HERE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_uNmWu5XVAhWEx4MKHcNYAQQQFgg8MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftrailhead.salesforce.com%2Fen%2Fmodules%2Fapex_testing%2Funits%2Fapex_testing_data&usg=AFQjCNHUOe2hyGPCOZVpBYxF_n2wB5tZsQ)) to create an account and an opportunity for that account (for example a createTestAccount and createTestOpportunity class).

Then create an instance of the controller class in a test class and do some assertions (see [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm) for a good example)